# I'd like to take an access log of an application to see who is accessing which page and how much

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, analysis

I'd like to analyse access log of an application to see who is accessing which page and how much.

That app is running on Cloud Foundry.
application: django3.1.
platform: ibm cloud.
web server: gnicorn.
user: Login user. I can identify the user.

I think that I can see the load in IBM Log Analysis with LogDNA.
But I think it can't show who accessed which page.

Q1. Is my thoughts correct?

Q2. Could you let me know if there are other IBM service to achieve my goals.

how to take log

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

setting file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s',
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'stt.log',  
            'formatter': 'default',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
    
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
       
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of application, which compute platform, which type of web server, are users logged in, data privacy considerations...?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information. application: django. platform: ibm cloud web server: gnicorn. user: Login user. I can identify the user.

Comment: Is that app running on Kubernetes, Cloud Foundry, VMware, VPC VM, ...? I am asking because some have plugins, some just directly interface

Comment: And please add your answers as well as the current code showing how you log to the question.

Comment: That app is running on Cloud Foundry.